# Joi validation for hapi-nuxt available with npx create-nuxt-app?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, joi, hapi

I created a demo app with `npx create-nuxt-app` to learn about nuxt.js. My installation options included:

```
? Use a custom server framework hapi
? Choose features to install Linter / Formatter, Prettier, Axios
? Use a custom UI framework buefy
? Choose rendering mode Single Page App
```

However, I did not see an option for installing Joi. What is the right way to install Joi when using `npx create-nuxt-app`? Is the best choice to run this afterwards?

```
npm install --save joi
```

I did it that way and it worked, but just because it worked initially doesn't mean it's correct. It's a simple question, but I'm new to all this, so just trying to learn best practices.